Compare group by and select all in mysql
I have a data table in MySQL and this table have a column with JSON data type. So I run and compared the two queries:
SELECT * 
FROM `table`;

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY JSON_EXTRACT(info, "$.id");

I noticed that the first query running slower than the second.
I thought that the second query has to be slower than the first.
Can you explain this? Thank you!
I am trying to understand how the second query running and why the second faster than the first.

You should run EXPLAIN on both queries.  The first SELECT * query may have to return a lot of data through the pipeline which might explain your observations.

Oh, I will run EXPLAIN on both queries to find out. Thank you! @TimBiegeleisen

With no information about table or its content, we cannot tell you much, nor will EXPLAIN. Both queries require a full table scan, with a temp table needed for the aggregation in the second query. As a generalisation, 2M rows of ten columns will take longer to transfer than a single column of integers.

Did you time each query twice?  This avoids I/O and caching.
